# matlab image comparison

Tags: image, matlab, fuzzy-logic, fuzzy-comparison

I am trying to set up a database of images that can be used to compare
to a current image (So if the current image is equal, or almost equal
to the one being compared it'll give a match)

However to start this project off I want to just compare 2 images
using Matlab to see how the process works.

Does anyone know how I might compare say image1.jpg and image2.jpg to
see how closely related to each other they are? So basically if I was
to compare image1.jpg and image1.jpg the relationship should be 100%,
but comparing 2 different images might give me quite a close
relationship.

I hope that makes some sense!!!

Thanks,

Comment: If you can add information about the problem you are trying to solve, I might be able to improve my answer with a more appropriate method

Comment: @KlausCPH i want to compare two images using matlab

Comment: Yes, I already got that part :-) But to say something more clever about the comparison algorithm, I need to know more about the actual problem you are trying to solve. E.g. what's in the images, how do two matching images differ, are matching images taken with the same camera,etc? I guess two matching images aren't completely equal in bit values? Because if that's the case my method below will do just fine

Comment: simple......i dont want to compare similar images...for ex i have all brand phone pic in my db.if i take a pic of nokia brand phone then it shows all similar product phone from my db(same size,diffenrent angels etc etc).....pls help

Comment: That is a really difficult problem to solve, and with currently known technology and algorithms one might argue that is is impossible to fully solve! So my method won't do for that. I suggest you do the classification manually.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the method to use greatly depend on what you define as similar images. If for example you can guarantee that translations (moves in the x and y directions) are very small (no more than a few pixels), a simple RMS subtraction measure might do fine. If this is not the case, brute force template search methods might be an option. At the other end of the scale are advanced recognition techniques using morphological measures.

The first and simplest approach might look something like this:

```
errorMeasure = sqrt(sum(sum(sum((image1-image2).^2))))
```

This method simple takes the difference and finds the "energy" of the error.